# tinymce rich text editor example not running

Tags: c#, javascript, html, tinymce

here is my script of tinymce.......in start i wanted this for asp.net i have tried this much time also some of script which are given on its main site ... even also have copy paste it but not work this below code also copy paste but not working then i think i try it with simple page but then also not working...working not means ...its even not showing i have not puted visibility:hidden; but when i run and see in browser no textarea coming which i have used it when u try to inspect element there i see **style="visibility:hidden"** how i not know ? and how i can run this..i want fully functional tinymce javascript if can provide or can solve this problem also i want this run for c# so pls help me .......also if u got better rich text editor free let me know..which can give me faster results

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
]
    });
</script>
```

here is my body code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
hi hello
<textarea name="content" style="width: 100%" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey thx for answer......... problem solved by this following ......and thx for help appreciate it

also u said to include css files i tried and remove it then also working so no needed of css :)

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
"searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
"insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
"emoticons template paste textcolor "],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the css file "tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css" has been loaded in the page?

Comment: yea i have added that skin.min.css